# How to ensure OpenCV actually runs OpenCL kernel?

Tags: opencv, opencl, nvidia, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to use ocl::remap() on HD video using OpenCV 2.4.8. However, I do not see any difference between purely CPU implementation of remap(), about 11 ms on my machine.

I see compiled kernels in the running directory named

```
imgproc_remap_NVIDIA CUDA_Quadro K1000M.clb
```

and

```
convertC3C4_NVIDIA CUDA_Quadro K1000M.clb
```

Can I ensure somehow the kernel is actually run? And if so, why is it so slow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run your application in nvidia visual profiler & collect timeline. It will show you kernels execution time & different statistics, which is useful for analysis.